# How to clean up jquery_mobile.css file?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Google Chrome audit reports that jquery_mobile.css takes 904 KB (minified) and 87% of it is not used in the current page most pages in my web app are similar. I wonder if there is a simple way to clean up that file and remove all the styles that are not used to save data transfer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple way since jquery ships with a huge number of controls. You would be the only one who knows which ones you are using and which ones you are not.

The only way I see to reduce the size of your CSS is to use the github repo https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/tree/master/css and just pick the CSS files for the components you are using.

That would mean having to get the updates manually when there is a new release rather than just dropping the CSS file from the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried to keep adding relevant css files to my project but never achieved to show the view as it does when I add the whole stuff. In any case I'm starting to think about removing jquery mobile completely, it feels like a waste of data...

Comment: Make sure you include the files from the "theme" folder when you add individual files. The theme is what has most of the generic styling.

Comment: Yeah I did add files from theme. I got to a point where everything was ok but I would see loading icon static down the page so I forgot the whole thing. Actually I got very frustrated with jquery mobile "magic" causing issues and taking so much to load. I removed it completely and the loading time is now 3.5 seconds, before it was 15 seconds! And I control everything with no hidden tricks. So goodbye jquery mobile from now on... Thanks for your hints codemonkey.